# C++ boost asio multithread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.asio-scalability

I am studying boost.asio and it arouse my curiosity. There is a source(Example 32.3)

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::asio;

int main()
{
  io_service ioservice;

  steady_timer timer1{ioservice, std::chrono::seconds{3}};
  timer1.async_wait([](const boost::system::error_code &ec)
    { std::cout << "3 sec\n"; });

  steady_timer timer2{ioservice, std::chrono::seconds{3}};
  timer2.async_wait([](const boost::system::error_code &ec)
    { std::cout << "3 sec\n"; });

  std::thread thread1{[&ioservice](){ ioservice.run(); }};
//std::thread thread2{[&ioservice](){ ioservice.run(); }};
  thread1.join();
//thread2.join();
}
```

Although I omit thread2, the screen output is equals. The number of thread in original example is two and the number of thread in this source is one. Although the number of thread is one, the timer1 and timer2 start and finish at the same time.

I wonder why the number of thread must be two.
Thank you for your concerning!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of the example is that you can have many threads calling `ioservice.run()` to get more scalable code. With the two thread version it is possible that the `timer1` and `timer2` handlers are processed in different threads, and that you can therefore get parallelism to improve performance.

The example does not show that well, as you have demonstrated. To see the real difference, try this as the handler for both timers, and compare the one and two thread versions:

```
timer1.async_wait([](const boost::system_error::error_code& ec) {
    std::cout << "3 sec, pausing\n";
    sleep(4);
    std::cout << "Finished pausing\n";
});
```

Comment: while this /works/ it is actually a bad example for async programming; Async handlers should not do blocking tasks. Otherwise you can easily starve the IO tasks. Use a queue and dedicated workers to handle the longer running tasks. Other than that, the explanation is on point, so +1

Comment: @sehe I agree -- the purpose of this example is to demonstrate concurrent or sequential handler execution by showing handler entry and exit on a human scale.

Comment: Thank you for your help.